# Difficulty in proving that closure of an open ball of radius $r$ is a closed ball.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space and $A$ be a subset of $X$ such that for some $p\in X$ and $\delta \gt 0$, we have $A=\{a\in X: d(a,p)\lt \delta\}$. Let's define $B=\{b\in X: d(b,p)\le\delta\}$. 
Let $\bar A=$ Closure of $A=A\cup A'$, where $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$. 
I am trying to prove that $\bar A= B$.

For any $x\in B$, we have $d(p,x)\le \delta$ so either $d(p,x)\lt \delta $ or $d(p,x)=\delta$. 
If $d(p,x)\lt \delta $, then $x\in A\subseteq A\cup A'$

However, if $d(p,x)=\delta$, then I am having difficulty in showing $x\in \bar A$. I tried as follows:

Let $0\lt\epsilon \lt \delta$, choose $z\in A$ such that $\delta \gt d(p,z)\gt \delta -\epsilon$, then we must have 
$d(x,p)+d(p,z)\ge d(x,z)\implies d(x,z)\le 2\delta$. I am stuck here.

**I want to show that $d(x,z)\lt \epsilon$ which would prove that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ i.e., $x\in A'\subseteq A\cup A'$**

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is generally not true unless it is a normed vector space. For example, consider the metric space $(-\infty, -1] \cup [0, \infty)$. The closure of the unit ball is $[0,1]$, which does not include $-1$.

Comment: Very nice counterexample. Thanks a lot.